# String camelize slow performance

Tags: php

So I have this piece of code in a static method called `Camelize`

```
return strtr(ucwords(strtr($id, array('_' => ' ', '.' => '_ ', '\\' => '_ '))), array(' ' => ''));
```

That just camelizes stuff.

I have around 211k records, iterating over a while loop, theese records have some words I need to camelize, longest word can be about 10 characters, easy peasy, but running some xhprof tests I concluded that camelize is not a good idea if you need speed.

**XHProf with camelize**: 313,866,303 microseconds (~5min)

- 19,268,795 calls
- Incl. Wall Time 228,658,500
- ICpu: 81.3%

**XHProf without camelize**: 55,099,811 microseconds (<1min)

The purpose of this script is to set values to class properties.

A property can be `protected $myVar`, which is camelized.

Inside my constructor, I get an array of ***underscore*** properties (array keys), and their values (array values). `my_var => foo`

As we have camelized properties, we need to convert the array keys to camelize, so we can do something like
`$this->$camelizedProperty = $value`

Yeah, we could have been using underscore properties so we don't need to convert any string, but this is an old working code, that now has about 4x times the properties it had, and it is being used by a lot of dependencies, so changing properties to underscore is not an option right now if we can find a way to speed up camelizing.

***UPDATE***

Using some individual tests with `microtime`  to get a realtime comparison I ended up with this...

Methods used:

1. `strtr(ucwords(strtr($word, array('_' => ' ', '.' => '_ ', '\\' => '_ '))), array(' ' => ''))`
2. `lcfirst(str_replace(" ", "", ucwords(strtr($word, "_-", "  "))))`
3. `str_replace(" ", "", ucwords(strtr($word, "_-", "  ")))`

Average results over the ~100 strings each iteration:

1. 0.0011
2. 0.0002
3. 0.0002

So as @RST pointed, using `str_replace` is 18% faster than my first method, but still slow (if we have a huge loop)

At 20M records, using xhprof, total results are:

1. 313 seconds (~5min)
2. 152 seconds (~2.5min)
3. 158 seconds (~2.5min)

We can say that `lcfirst` doesn't slow the script (I thought that may cause some slower times).

This question is not about how to camelize but about how it affects performance in our scripts, and which could be the best way to use it.

Comment: what do you mean with `inline piece of code` ?

Comment: I mean not calling an static method from another class, or a method basically. "camelizing" the string instead of calling any camelize method.

Comment: What are you applying it on? If it's database records, why not keep the finalized form cached in the database?

Comment: According to PHP manual you could win some time changing to `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: Again, just use a static list for mapping the most frequent property names. You can't possibly have 20M different ones?

Comment: Using a static list will make the script unmaintainable, because we will need to check it out everytime just to check if we mapped every field in there... And this script is executed often, that's not an option as I said, maybe our last option, but if I can optimize the performance, would be better.

Comment: What is it in specific you are doing here? Why are you trying to dump 211k records into objects? Are you sure you shouldn't take a step back and fix the actual problem somewhere?

Comment: @PeeHaaWe are migratin data between databases, and total data is about 1.5M, 211k are only test records, so the script will get even slower. We are 100% sure we need to use this script as there isn't another way we can migrate this data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how important it is to get faster times, you could replace the built in PHP function calls with a single pass string iteration for each of your input strings.

Times for 20 million records are as follows:

```
Method 1 time: 301.143823 
Method 2 time: 54.648126
```

Admittedly, the code here may look somewhat uglier but it will apparently chop the time down. Note, with 5 input strings just set the run quantity variable ($runqty) to 4 million to get 20 million record timings for each of the methods - be sure to comment out the echo statements in the loops first.

Sample code...

```
<?php

$input = array();
$input['my_var'] = 'foo';
$input['this.that'] = 'blah';
$input['try\\me'] = 'strange';
$input['some_var_here'] = 'value';
$input['final_cut'] = 'fc99';

set_time_limit(600);

$runqty = 1;

// Method 1
$m1start = microtime(true);
for ($runs = 0; $runs < $runqty; $runs++)
{
  foreach ($input as $word => $val)
  {
    $out = strtr(ucwords(strtr($word, array('_' => ' ', '.' => '_ ', '\\' => '_ '))), array(' ' => ''));
    echo "in: $word out: $out<br>\n";
  }
}
$m1stop = microtime(true);
$m1time = $m1stop - $m1start;
echo "Method 1 time: " . sprintf("%0.6f",$m1time);
echo "<br>\n";

// Method 2
$m2start = microtime(true);
for ($runs = 0; $runs < $runqty; $runs++)
{
  foreach ($input as $word => $val)
  {
    $i=0;
    $len = strlen($word);
    $ucnext = true;
    $out = '';

    while ( $i < $len )
    {
      $char = $word[$i++];
      if ( $char == '_' || $char == '.' || $char == '\\' )
      {
        $ucnext = true;
        if ( $char == '.' )
          $char ='_';
        else
          $char = '';
      }
      else
      {
        if ( $ucnext )
        {
          if ( $char >= 'a' && $char <= 'z' )
            $char = ucfirst($char);
          $ucnext = false;
        }
      }

      $out .= $char;
    }
    echo "in: $word out: $out<br>\n";
  }
}
$m2stop = microtime(true);
$m2time = $m2stop - $m2start;
echo "Method 2 time: " . sprintf("%0.6f",$m2time);
echo "<br>\n";
```

Note: If you didn't want the first letter capitalized then simply initialize the ucnext variable to false (instead of true as shown).